# PHP Get value then put it to a variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have a code to do this:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("d2ladder.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xp1 = 4439;
$xp2 = 8439;
?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
<?php $xp = $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->experience;
      $xppercent = $xp/$xp2*100; ?>

      <div style="width: <?php echo $xppercent; ?>px">teste</div>
<?php echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

That `"$xp2"` on the formula need to be set by the `$xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level`

if level = 1 then calculate with `$xp1`
if level = 2 calculate with `$xp2` and goes, I've got 99 fixed xps that varies level 1-99 to calculate in that way

There's a simple way to solve this? thanks

Comment: Sorry, i do not exactly understand what you want. Where is `$xp1` used?

Comment: $xp1 will be used for level 1, $xp2 for level 2 ... $xp99 for level 99.. needing something like $xp[level] and this returns $xpX(1-99) and then get the fixed value to calculate the percent

Comment: i got it. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an array for `$xp1`, `$xp2` etc., you could always use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("d2ladder.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xp1 = 4439;
$xp2 = 8439;
// And so on ...

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $xp = $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->experience;
    $xppercent = $xp/${'xp' . xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level}*100;
    echo "<div style=\"width:$xppercent;px\">teste</div>";
    echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level;
}
```

Comment: But with this you flood your namespace with 99 of unnecessary variables. And it is harder to read.

Comment: @u-nik I know, I'm just providing an alternative answer. Plus, it's always good to know about variable variables, you'd be surprised how many so-called "developers" don't know about them.

Comment: This seems to work, but now I got another problem.. just saw that my information has a space before the numbers with less than 2 algorithms.. <level> 8</level> , see that space before 8? for others it's ok <level>10</level> for example

Comment: Then It gets an error Notice: Undefined variable: xp 3 ..because of that space, there's a way to the variable have a space? or to easy remove that space of 1 to 9?

Comment: Just trim your variable : `$xppercent = $xp/${'xp' . trim(xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level)}*100;` if you're using variable variables, or `$xppercent = $xp / $xps[trim($xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level)] * 100;`if you're using arrays

Comment: Really? Thats the solution you will use? :-O Yes, it will work, but... thats not really performant with concating, trim and hard to read...

Comment: I have to admit, even though I wrote this answer, I think @u-nik's one with the array is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So it's like, when level = 1, $xp1, level 2 - $xp2, level 3 - $xp1?

If that's the case, use modulo:

```
//if 1, number uneven, if 0, number even. uneven = $xp1, even = $xp2;
$isEven = $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level % 2;
if ($isEven === 0) {
    //use $xp1
} else {
   //use $xp2
}
```

Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I need to give more details. I'll have a list of "xps" 1 till 99 with fixed values, and 1-99 levels for each xp..

Comment: The use an array to hold all XPs for the levels like `$xp[$level]`

Comment: Hmm that's the way, with an array, I'm exploring it, but if you could help with some exemple would be better! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("d2ladder.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xps = [
    1 => 4439,
    2 => 8439,
    // ... and so on
];

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $xp        = $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->experience;
    $xppercent = $xp / $xps[$xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level] * 100;

    echo "<div style=\"width:$xppercent;px\">teste</div>";
    echo $xml->ladder[12]->char[$i]->level;
}
```

if u use an older php, change array notation to `$xps = array(/*...*/);`

Comment: Got this error with this: Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\9-SITES\d2evo\ladder.php on line 114

Warning: Division by zero in C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\9-SITES\d2evo\ladder.php on line 114.. maybe the problem is.... see my comment to roberto06's post

Comment: Devision by zero occurs if your xps is not defined or 0. Do you have defined all available levels in the `$xps` array?